Unable to log in as mysql root user in Laravel Sail
I'm trying to grant privileges to my "sail" mysql user, but when I log in as root it is logging me in as sail instead.
I should note that I can connect to mysql fine in PHPStorms db browser (even as root).
Here are the steps that leads to this problem
Inside the project directory on my host machine, I type the following:
sail mysql -u root -p


This command successfully logs me in, but whenever I try to run any commands I get an error, for example:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sail'@'%';

returns the following error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' (using password: YES)


and if I run:
SELECT CURRENT_USER();


I get the following response:
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| sail@%         |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


I've also tried using
sail root-shell

to then try and login to mysql inside there, but I get the following error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)


Anyone have any ideas of anything else I can try?

That error doesn't seem to be caused by privileges. Perhaps you have a dangling connection somewhere? Sail is finicky when you have multiple containers up all trying to connect to the same ports. Usually I just reboot when it happens to me, or try adding a FORWARD_DB_PORT env variable

Sail v1.30.2
sail shell

In Docker container
mysql -h mysql -u root -ppassword

If this doesn't work, recreate the Docker volume.

I can now log in as root, thank you.
